# QT: Context menu (QMenu) reference from the QTableWidget

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to add a submenu in my context menu which is created like this:

```
self.widget_alignment.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.ActionsContextMenu)
```

where widget_alignment is **QTableWidget**.

I created a new QMenu instance:

```
exchange_bases_menu = QMenu(self.widget_alignment)
```

added some actions, and I found a method [QAction QMenu.addMenu (self, QMenu menu)](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qmenu.html#addMenu)

but I don't see any reference to the default context menu for self.widget_alignment.
Additionally, this code:

```
self.widget_alignment.addMenu(exchange_bases_menu)
```

gave me: QTableWidget object has no attribute addMenu.

How can I add my submenu to the default context menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, when a `QWidget` is set to have the actions context menu type, the widget will construct a context menu based on the list of actions set for the widget.  To modify the list of actions, you can call `addAction`, `insertAction`, or `removeAction`.  So I would expect you could do something like this (in C++):

```
QAction *act_p = new QAction( "Has Submenu", widget_alignment );
QMenu *submenu_p = new QMenu( act_p );
// Add items to the submenu
act_p->setMenu( submenu_p );
widget_alignment->addAction( act_p );
```

Without trying it myself, I would expect this to add a "Has Submenu" option to the bottom of the context menu that is generated for the widget, with the submenu you created as the submenu shown.

Comment: Thanks cjhuitt!

That's what works for me (in Python):

act_p = QAction( "Has Submenu", self.widget_alignment)
submenu_p = QMenu(self.widget_alignment)

# Add items to the submenu
sa = QAction("Submenu action", submenu_p)
submenu_p.addAction(sa)

act_p.setMenu(submenu_p)
self.widget_alignment.addAction(act_p)

Answer (score 0):

What about using QMenu's popup() in MouseReleaseEvent?

```
if (pEvent->button() == Qt::RightButton)
{
    QMenu menu;
    menu.addAction(action1);
    menu.addAction(action2);
    menu.popup(pEvent->globalPos(),action1);
}
```